# Creating a Cognito UserPool with lambda's configured as triggers

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am attempting to create a Cognito user pool programmatically from a script using the JavaScript SDK.

I have successfully created the user-pool and defined a pre-signup and post-confirmation trigger by specifying the arn's of the relevant lambdas in my config. (as per the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#createUserPool-property))

My script looks like this:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const awsConfig = require('../config/config');

aws.config.update({ region: awsConfig.REGION });

const provider = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();


// user provided args
const stage = process.argv[2];

if (!stage) {
  process.stdout.write('Please provide stage as argument\n');
  process.exit(1);
}


// generate arns for pre and post cognito triggers
const getArn = (lambdaName) => {
  return `arn:aws:lambda:${awsConfig.REGION}:${awsConfig.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}` +
         `:function:my-project-name-${stage}-${lambdaName}`;
};

const preSignUp = getArn('preSignUp');
const postConfirmation = getArn('postConfirmation');


const userPoolConfig = {
  PoolName: `mypool-${stage}`,
  AutoVerifiedAttributes: ['email'],
  Schema: [
    {
      "StringAttributeConstraints": {
        "MaxLength": "2048",
        "MinLength": "0"
      },
      "Mutable": true,
      "Required": true,
      "AttributeDataType": "String",
      "Name": "email",
      "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false
    }
  ],
  LambdaConfig: {
    PostConfirmation: postConfirmation,
    PreSignUp: preSignUp
  }
};


const callback = (err, resp) => {
  if (err) {
    process.stdout.write(`${err}\n`);
  } else {
    process.stdout.write(resp.UserPool.Id);
  }
};


provider.createUserPool(userPoolConfig, callback);
```

When I run this script it successfully creates the user pool, an and when I inspect it in the console the triggers are set correctly.

When I try to register a user on my user pool I get the error:

```
AccessDeniedException { code: 'UnexpectedLambdaException', ... }
```

If I go into the console and set the trigger manually it works just fine.

This bug has been reported - but I see no confirmation, nor solution:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2256

Desperately unable to fix or find a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. The issue is that the lambda does not have the correct permissions to interact with cognito.

I found this snippet of information hidden away [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=748566)

So the in the callback function for the create user pool I attached the correct permissions like this:

```
const callback = (err, resp) => {
  if (err) {
    process.stdout.write(`${err}\n`);
  } else {

    const userPoolId = resp.UserPool.Id;

    // the lambdas must have a permission attached that allows them to interact
    // directly with cognito
    const generateLambdaPersmission = (userPoolName, lambdaName) => {
      return {
        Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
        Principal: 'cognito-idp.amazonaws.com',
        SourceArn: `arn:aws:cognito-idp:${awsConfig.REGION}:${awsConfig.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:userpool/${userPoolId}`,
        FunctionName: getArn(lambdaName),
        StatementId: `${stage}1`
      };
    };

    lambda.addPermission(generateLambdaPersmission(userPoolId, 'preSignUp'), (err, resp) => {
      if (err) {
        process.stdout.write(`error attaching permission to lambda: ${err}`);
      }
    });

    lambda.addPermission(generateLambdaPersmission(userPoolId, 'postConfirmation'), (err, resp) => {
      if (err) {
        process.stdout.write(`error attaching permission to lambda: ${err}`);
      }
    });

    process.stdout.write(userPoolId);
  }
};
```

See the documentation on adding permissions via the JavaScript SDK [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#addPermission-property)

Answer (score 21):

If you need to add the permission in a serverless.yml file then this is what worked for us. Add it to your Resources section:

```
UserPoolLambdaInvokePermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    Action: lambda:invokeFunction
    Principal: cognito-idp.amazonaws.com
    FunctionName: <function-name>
    SourceArn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:<your region>:<your account>:userpool/*
```

This gives all the user pools the ability to invoke your particular function.

You can get the function name to use by looking in .serverless/serverless-state.json and there against your lambda you'll see the FunctionName property.

Answer (score 7):

If you have set up your user pool and lambda triggers in cloud formation you will need to add the appropirate permissions for the user pool to invoke the lambda function.

You would have to add something like this to your cloud formation template.

```
"UserPoolPreSignupLambdaInvokePermission"    : {
    "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
    "Properties" : {
        "Action" : "lambda:invokeFunction",
        "Principal" : "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com",
        "FunctionName" :{ "Ref" : "AutoVerifyEmailPreSignupLambdaFunction" },
        "SourceArn"    : {
            "Fn::Sub" : "arn:aws:cognito-idp:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:userpool/${UserPool}"
        }
    }
}
```